# Eliminar objetos de una matriz de array segun una propiedad especifica en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, ecmascript-6

Tengo un array de objetos random y quiero eliminar a aquellos cuya propiedad sea IGUAL a mi variable `author`, dentro del array tengo dos `author` (no quiero eliminar usando 'carlitos', si no la variable `author`)

```
let posts = [
  { title: 'javascript', author: 'pepe', id: 5 },
  { title: 'react', author: 'carlitos', id: 3 },
  { title: 'sql', author: 'carlitos', id: 7 },
];

let author = 'carlitos';
```

Si hago un `.filter` de esta manera para averiguar en primer lugar que `author` exista dentro del arreglo hago un `.filter`, y esto me devuelve:

```
const authorPosts = posts.filter(p => p.author === author);
console.log(authorPosts) //los dos objetos con carlitos
```

Acá tengo que comprobar si el author no existe tira error y luego SI EXISTE eliminar en mi arreglo posts TODOS los objetos que coincidan con ese AUTHOR

Pense en buscar con un filter (aunque es un poco repetitivo el codigo)

```
let eliminados = posts.filter(el => el.author !== author);
```

Despues que posts sea igual a esa variable para poder reemplazar sus valores posts = eliminados;

Ahora quiero retorar los VALORES ELIMINADOS, no el arreglo de posts que me quedo

```
return eliminados;
```

No me pasan los tests con esto, estuve buscando otras formas, pero no las pude implementar.

Esta de abajo la vi en internet.. queria obtener los indices de los objetos pertencientes a dicho author y despues filtrarlos.

```
var indices = posts.map((e, i) => e.author === author ? i : '').filter(String);
```

O usar un splice... pero no entendi la documentación.

```
posts.splice(0, indices)
```

No quiero hacer ciclos for y todo eso, me interesa aprender a implementar metodos de arrays que es lo que mas cuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo quieres armar 2 grupos, `.filter` es mas útil cuando queremos un solo grupo, para armar 2 o mas es mejor `.reduce` o un for, según mi opinión.

```js
const posts = [
  { title: 'javascript', author: 'pepe', id: 5 },
  { title: 'react', author: 'carlitos', id: 3 },
  { title: 'sql', author: 'carlitos', id: 7 },
];

const author = 'carlitos';

const res = posts.reduce((p, c) => {

  (c.author === author) ? p[0].push(c): p[1].push(c);

  return p;
}, [ [], [] ]);


console.log(res[0]); //<-- tiene carlitos

console.log(res[1]); //<-- no tiene carlitos
```

Comment: hola, gracias por la rta,  no entiendo en el segundo parametro los dos arrays vacios, se va pusheando en un u otro segun el condicional ternario? se asocia p a un array y c a otro? y cuando se retorna p, se retornarian los dos arrays o si quiero la primera opcion siempre tengo que decirle p en la posicion 0 ?

Comment: Claro, se va pusheando en uno u otro, el segundo parámetro del reduce es el objeto inicial, que sera la estructura de la devolución.

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo! ahora entiendo mejor el reduce, lo voy a seguir practicando :)